# Create own Wordpress Front End on specific Page

Tags: wordpress

i'm writing my first Plugin for Wordpress. A booking calendar. The Admin and Setting Page is already working. The Admin has the possibility to create, edit and delete bookings. I'm struggling with the Front End.

How do i call my "Create a Booking" Form for the User?

Do i need do create a separate Page for that or is it possible for the Admin to call my "Create a Booking" Form in every Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways... The simplest would be to put your form directly into the content of a page or post. In that case, anyone could access the form. If you need to dynamically determine how the form is displayed, you'll want to put it into a shortcode, or use a Wordress page-template in your theme [confusing, because this is totally different from a page!]. Use shortcodes to port your project to any theme, use page templates to lock your functionality into one specific theme. To alter every page, you would put your functionality in a plugin, or in your theme's functions.php file.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/